# Error while compile code with Xseed tool in Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have issue while compiling the code using Xseed tool. Tool runs fine for datadef generation but i get below error prompted on window. I have not done any change with tools configuration.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: XseedGenerate.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    546cadf6
  Fault Module Name:    XseedJAccessRoutine.DLL
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   51dc06cf
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000c2004
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    5129
  Additional Information 1: 42aa
  Additional Information 2: 42aaa4d06451b11724a68d4202e08a6f
  Additional Information 3: 6550
  Additional Information 4: 6550caa965b0941d4062d69a476a1a06

Read our privacy statement online: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline: C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

2. I suspect build failure on jenkins is also because of this. I have different error message in log in Jenkins.

   ```
   F:\Jenkins\jobs\Dev_754_FeatureConsolidation01_Clean01\workspace\src\Build\generate.xml:82: exec returned: 255
       at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:401)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
   Caused by: F:\Jenkins\jobs\Dev_754_FeatureConsolidation01_Clean01\workspace\src\Build\generate.xml:130: The following error occurred while executing this line:
   F:\Jenkins\jobs\Dev_754_FeatureConsolidation01_Clean01\workspace\src\Build\generate.xml:147: The following error occurred while executing this line:
   F:\Jenkins\jobs\Dev_754_FeatureConsolidation01_Clean01\workspace\src\Build\generate.xml:82: exec returned: 255
       at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:401)
       at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
       at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
       at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:324)
   ```

Any one have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins was not able to recognize the long name. I think there is limit set for the naming conventions for jobs on Jenkins. After all the hard work on Configuration etc. When i configured new job with shorter and meaningful name problem was resolved. Hope this helps someone.